# How to assign values in the cookies Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have the following Cookie Name and Cookie Item in a CBLL class as

```
    public const string COOKIE_NAME_TDR_FILTER = "jS.TDR.Filter";
    public const string COOKIE_DF_KEY = "DFKey";
```

In the Page we try to assign the values to the cookies so it can be used in the called pages, `.aspx.cs`.

```
   protected string TDRFilterCookieName = CBLL.COOKIE_NAME_TDR_FILTER;
   protected string CookieDFKey = CBLL.COOKIE_DF_KEY;
```

In the .aspx  using the javascript I am trying to assign the values for the CookieDFKey. So it can be used later.

```
  var cookie = new Cookie("<%= this.TDRFilterCookieName%>");
  cookie.<%= this.CookieDFKey %> = id;
  cookie.store();
  alert(cookie.<%= this.CookieDFKey %>);
```

Tried the above code but it throws error like Cookie() is not defined. Please help me with this as I am new to JS Script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read [documentation about cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

```
// To create a cookie
document.cookie = "${key}=${value}"; // optional expiration date, see doc.

// To add a new cookie
document.cookie = "${key}=${value}"; // As you can see, `document.cookie` is not a normal Object holding a string
```

W3 Schools provides very good methods to add/get cookies, that I will copy/paste here (All the credit goes to them):

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

And a function `deleteCookie(cname)` that I just wrote:

```
function deleteCookie(cname) {
    document.cookie = cname + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
}
```

Comment: What is the pair of `key : value` that you actually need to store? `CookieDFKey : TDRFilterCookieName`? Or maybe `CookieDFKey : id`?

Comment: Key Should be `CookieDFKey` and value should be `id`. How should be we giving without the expiration date.

Comment: Import the `setCookie` function above, and then just call it by `setCookie(<%= this.CookieDFKey %>, id, 30)`. There has to be an expiration date. The cookie is deleted by default when the browser is closed when you don't specify any. By putting 30, the cookie will expire after a month. You can put more days if you need them.

Comment: But is it possible to have just the key and value without expiration

Comment: No. A cookie has to have an expiration. If you want to store data permanently, using a server and database would be a good choice.